# Interactive function with SelectMultiple widgets arranged in a HBox

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, interactive, ipywidgets

I would like to build an interactive app with a Jupyter notebook and I do not have much experience with widgets yet.

In my code, I define 2 SelectMultiple widgets (see definition in code below).

I combine the 2 widgets in a certain layout using for example 'HBox' (see code).

I have also defined a function that based on the values of these 2 widgets searches in a database and returns an integer equal to the number of selected elements in the database (see code below).

I would like to print the output of the function "No_selected" so that it changes interactively when I choose a different input in one of the 2 SelectMultiple widgets displayed in the HBox layout.

I have tried to read the documentation for the widgets (https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide.html).

I have tried to use the Interact decorator '@ Interact' before the function but when I do it Jupyter displays two extra widgets for W1 and W2 instead of allowing me to run the function by using the two widgets in the HBox.

Example of widget definition for W1 (and similar for W2):

```py
W1 = widgets.SelectMultiple(
    options=['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears'],
    value=['Oranges'],
    #rows=10,
    description='Fruits',
    disabled=False
)
```

Example of layout:

```py
Wboth = widgets.HBox([W1, W2])
```

Example of function definition:

```py
def SELECTION(W1=('Apples'), W2=('Apples')):
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return No_selected
```

Can you please suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will need something a bit more involved than a standard `interact` here as you need to get information from more than just the widget you are changing.

I've put together a `class` version of the behaviour you want, I find myself using `observe` much more than `interact` now I am more familiar with composition and subclassing. You can change your _observed_function to do what you need with the current widget selections.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

class SelectMultipleInteract(widgets.HBox):

    def __init__(self):
        self.W1 = widgets.SelectMultiple(
            options=['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears'],
            value=['Oranges'],
            #rows=10,
            description='Fruits',
            disabled=False
        )

        self.W2 = widgets.SelectMultiple(
            options=['Carrots', 'Potatoes', 'Tomatoes'],
            value=['Carrots'],
            #rows=10,
            description='Veg',
            disabled=False
        )

        self.selectors = [self.W1, self.W2]
        super().__init__(children=self.selectors)
        self._set_observes()

    def _set_observes(self):
        for widg in self.selectors:
            widg.observe(self._observed_function, names='value')

    def _observed_function(self, widg):
        for widg in self.selectors:
            print(widg.description)
            print(widg.get_interact_value())

SelectMultipleInteract()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to follow your suggestion and it works. Furthermore I understood better how to use 'observe'.

Comment: And the following works: 
Whbox = widgets.HBox([W1, W2, W3])
def Update(W1,W2,W3):
    Wno_selected = Jselect(W1.value, W2.value, W3.value)
    
display(Whbox)

W1.observe(Update, 'value')
W2.observe(Update, 'value')
W3.observe(Update, 'value')

display(Wno_selected)

Comment: What would be the path if I needed to update the options of one widget based on the choice of the other, using this approach?

Comment: You can set `W2.options` in a function which is observed by W1. Just be careful not to get into a feedback loop where W1 alters W2, which alters W1 etc.